# How to create Distribution Certificate automatically with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, certificate

Followed by Apple recommendation to use Xcode to Create a Distribution Certificate and info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html

a can't create that certificate at all!! Already deleted all my keys, certificates and provisionin profiles several times to start from clean ground up but nothing. Xcode succesfuly created only Development certificate automatically not the Distribution one (i have Admin role in team not agent).

When i create that certificate manualy i'm forced to end up with two keys in my keychains - one created by Xcode in development certificate creation process, and the secod one (with identical info) i must create manually for Distribution Certeficat in CSR process!

So, has anyone managed to create that distrubution certificate with Xcode4.5

Answer (score 5):

You can only have 1 distribution certificate per developer team. You have to manually download it from the provisioning portal, as well, you can't install it through organizer as far as I'm aware.

Log in to developer.apple.com, click iOS provisioning portal, click Certificates, then click Distribution. You should see the distribution certificate there, which you can download. Note- if someone else installed the certificate, I'm pretty sure you will be unable to install it from the download. You'll have to export it from their keychain.

Edit after 6 years- You can now have more distribution certificates per team. 3 for an App Store account, 2 for Enterprise.